# strange MSTest output breaking xml report

Tags: mstest

I am running tests outside VS using mstest, and getting a wierd character on the end of the test report. The command line is:

mstest /testmetadata:matrix.vsmdi /testlist:"Build Server" /runconfig:ManualTestMatrix.testrunconfig /resultsfile:BuildServer.trx > %outPath%

and the last part of the output is:

```
    <UnitTestResult executionId="073daca5-28c9-4a29-806f-d55414ac045a" testId="64bc10d0-cb16-1d61-5f02-7ff241a2dec6" testName="MatrixSampleResult_DoubleBlind_DoubleBlindResultStatus_Stage1Entered" computerName="HP6550BTS2" duration="00:00:00.0037216" startTime="2014-09-09T16:28:09.5883032+01:00" endTime="2014-09-09T16:28:09.6093011+01:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="2fc4d891-506d-45de-8c61-cf6aa44e8eb2">
      <Output>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
    <UnitTestResult executionId="51df5b4e-bfe3-43fe-81a1-7029d81ed4d9" testId="d531a0bd-97b5-5c95-b1e8-bc6a60be958a" testName="MatrixSampleResult_ComponentType_AppearsAsDirectText_MergeIsTrue" computerName="HP6550BTS2" duration="00:00:00.0023969" startTime="2014-09-09T16:28:09.6113009+01:00" endTime="2014-09-09T16:28:09.6163004+01:00" testType="13cdc9d9-ddb5-4fa4-a97d-d965ccfc6d4b" outcome="Passed" testListId="2fc4d891-506d-45de-8c61-cf6aa44e8eb2">
      <Output>
      </Output>
    </UnitTestResult>
  </Results>
</TestRun>
```

After the final  there is a non-printable character that in notepad looks like a right-arrow, and in Notepad++ looks like SUB with a black background. Does any one know what is causing this? is it a bug in mstest?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `mstest.exe` over `vstest.console.exe`?

Comment: Only that the process should ideally also run on a machine not having Visual Studio installed. What does vstest.concole do that is different to mstest?